# Inconsistent Routing Results in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

Seems I'm still missing something to the MVC routing concept. I have a route that follows nearly the same pattern as another route in an area but for what ever reason I get a 404 every time I attempt to run it. I've tried to use Phil Haack's Route Tester DLL and according to that it hits the correct route (matched route comes out to common/itemhistory/{contentid}). When I try to run it for real, it blows up.

I'm trying to map a call to a JsonResult by passing a Guid. I've had success with other routes working fine (common is an area in my site).

What could I be doing wrong?

```
       context.MapRoute(
            "ItemHistory",
            "common/itemhistory/{contentid}",
            new { controller = "common", action = "GetItemHistory" },
            new { contentid = @"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$" }
        );


        context.MapRoute(
            "Common_default",
            "common/{action}",
            new { controller="common", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning action attribute to "**GetItemHistory**" and have defined **itemhistory** in the regular Route Pattern. Looks like you don't have a method in your controller by name "**GetItemHistory**"

Comment: Ahhh!!! I knew it was something obvious. I think I've been looking at the this stuff for too long. Good catch.